# Is secure create cookies with a token inside on the client?

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, graphql, jwt

i´m using nextjs, graphql and JWT on my app and I can´t find a good logic to send the cookie with the token inside from the server, so I found another logic based on create the cookie on the client when the server send me the token.

Is it insecure? Is a bad practice or there is any difference between creating cookies on the server or on the cliente? I´m using HTTP cookies.

this is my code on the client where I create the cookie:

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    createUser({variables: {nombre, apellidos, email, password}}).then(res=>{
      console.log(res.data.register)
      cookies.set("token", res.data.register,{sameSite:'strict', expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 140000000), httpOnly: true})
    })
```

In **res.data.register** is the token(JWT) created by server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is insecure.

You can't create an HTTP-only cookie on the client-side. HTTP-only means that no script is able to access the cookie, but you're already creating that cookie with a script. In fact, the browser won't let you set the HTTP-only flag on a cookie set from a script.

Your server should be sending a `Set-Cookie` header in the response, and this is where the cookie should be set, together with HTTP-only and sameSite parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, finally I have decided to try to send the cookie from the backend and I got it!